# Getting the following error while importing data from Firebase:The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a simple app that reads data from a Firestore Firebase and to show it on the app to the user. It is basically a simple blog app.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'dart:async';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot>subscription;

  List<DocumentSnapshot>snapshot;

  CollectionReference collectionReference=Firestore.instance.collection("Post");

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    subscription=collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot){
      setState(() {
        snapshot=datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Blog App Demo"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,

        actions: <Widget>[

          new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: ()=>debugPrint("Searching...")
          ),

          new IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              onPressed: ()=>debugPrint("Chilling...")
          )

        ],
      ),

      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text("Priyanuj Dey"),
                accountEmail: new Text("priyanujdey@gmail.com"),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),

            ),

            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Profile"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),          //trailing for right
            ),

            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Settings"),
              leading: new Icon(Icons.build, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),          //trailing for right
            ),

            new Divider(
              height: 10.0,
              color: Colors.black45,
            ),

            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Close"),
              trailing: new Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red),          //leading for left
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),



          ],
        )
      ),

      body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return new Card(
              elevation: 10.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

              child: new Container(

                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new CircleAvatar(
                    child: new Text(snapshot[index].data["title"][0]),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),

                  new SizedBox(width: 15.0,),

                  new Container(
                    width: 210.0,
                    child: new Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        new Text(snapshot[index].data["title"],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, color: Colors.lightGreen),
                          maxLines: 1,
                        ),

                        new SizedBox(height: 5.0,),

                        new Text(snapshot[index].data["content"],
                        maxLines: 2,

                        ),

                      ]
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ),
            )
            );
          }
      )



    );
  }
}
```

When there is a single entry in Firebase, the app works just fine, but as I enter another set of data, it shows me this error. 
Can anybody please help me with this.
I'm just starting to learn Flutter and a total noob in it.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure all your documents do have a 'title' field? Which line is throwing the error? I suppose it is

> child: new Text(snapshot[index].data["title"][0]),

where you are accessing the index 0 of a document that does not have a title.

2. This is not the prefered way to access Firestore streams in Flutter, since to have to take care of the lifecycle of the subscription by yourself. Consider using a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html). Here is an example of how to use it:

   ```
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
         stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Post").snapshots(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) //You are still loading data
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            return ListView.builder(...) //Here you do as you are used to
         } 
      )
   ```

Comment: Yes. I have a 'title' field.

Also, the issue comes when I add two or more rows in the firestore database. If there is only one, no issues. Uploading a screenshot of the app in here.

Comment: Errors:
Error: 'Userdata' isn't a type.
Error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncSnapshot<invalid-type>'.
Error: The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncSnapshot<invalid-type>'.
The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncSnapshot<invalid-type>'.
The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<invalid-type>'.
 - 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.

Comment: Sorry, the 'Userdata' was a leftover from where I copied it from. Use QuerySnapshot instead. I edited my comment

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas for your replies. But the issue was in my way of adding of data to the database. I somehow overlooked some silly mistakes and that created the issue.